# Hide elements in Sencha Touch but preserve CSS spacing

Tags: css, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, visibility, hidden

I have a view in Sencha Touch that contains many different labels and buttons.  I have styled them in my custom.css file to how I want them to look.  I want to hide everything but one button, so that when the button is clicked, the elements will appear.  I added to those elements "hidden: true."  However, the CSS is ignored and the styling is awful.  Is there any way to preserve the CSS?  I saw I could use 'hiddenCls" but I cannot figure out how to use it.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Below is my code so far:

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.StartScreen', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'startscreen',

config: {
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'middle'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        docked: 'top',
        title: 'My App',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            iconMask: true,
            iconCls: 'refresh',
            width: 42
        }, { xtype: 'spacer' }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            iconMask: true,
            iconCls: 'user'
        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'label',
        html: 'Discussions',
        cls: 'item-title-label',
        name: 'itemTitleLabel',
        hidden: true,
        hiddenCls: 'x-item-title-label-hidden'
    }, {
        xtype: 'label',
        html: 'Hi',
        cls: 'case-number-label',
        name: 'caseNumberLabel',
        hidden: true,
        hiddenCls: 'x-case-number-label-hidden'
    }, {
        xtype: 'label',
        html: '0:00',
        cls: 'duration-label',
        name: 'durationLabel',
        hidden: true,
        hiddenCls: 'x-duration-label-hidden'
    }, {
        xtype: 'label',
        html: 'Started at 13:42',
        cls: 'time-started-label',
        name: 'timeStartedLabel',
        hidden: true,
        hiddenCls: 'x-time-started-label-hidden'
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Start',
        ui: 'confirm',
        cls: 'big-start-button',
        name: 'bigStartButton'
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Off',
        ui: 'decline',
        cls: 'big-off-button',
        name: 'bigOffButton',
        hidden: true,
        hiddenCls: 'x-off-button-hidden'
    }]
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the css property `visiibility` on the elements you want to hide, as in `visibility:hidden`.

Comment: Thanks, that works.  But how can I set the visibility to true using my Sencha Touch code in the JavaScript?

Comment: @bnrq I don't know but you could use a class (e.g `.hidden{visibility :hidden}`) and add that class to the components you want to hide.

Comment: I actually figured it out! I can just use getElementById and then set the visibility to 'visible' (like: itemTitle.style.visibility = 'visible').  Thanks for your help!